# Getting a TypeError when using the Firebase Emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am trying to set up the Firebase Emulator but am getting the following error when attempting to use Firestore (Hosting, Functions and Auth are all working as expected).

[Error] TypeError: firebase.firestore().useEmulator is not a function. (In 'firebase.firestore().useEmulator(firebaseEmulators.firestore.host, firebaseEmulators.firestore.port)', 'firebase.firestore().useEmulator' is undefined)
Global Code (init.js:39)

Here is the relevant init.js code:

```
if (firebaseConfig) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  var firebaseEmulators = {
  "auth": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 9099
  },
  "firestore": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 8080
  },
  "functions": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5001
  }
};
  if (firebaseEmulators) {
    console.log("Automatically connecting Firebase SDKs to running emulators:");
    Object.keys(firebaseEmulators).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log('\t' + key + ': http://' +  firebaseEmulators[key].host + ':' + firebaseEmulators[key].port );
    });

    if (firebaseEmulators.database && typeof firebase.database === 'function') {
      firebase.database().useEmulator(firebaseEmulators.database.host, firebaseEmulators.database.port);
    }

    if (firebaseEmulators.firestore && typeof firebase.firestore === 'function') {
      firebase.firestore().useEmulator(firebaseEmulators.firestore.host, firebaseEmulators.firestore.port);
    }

    if (firebaseEmulators.functions && typeof firebase.functions === 'function') {
      firebase.functions().useEmulator(firebaseEmulators.functions.host, firebaseEmulators.functions.port);
    }

    if (firebaseEmulators.auth && typeof firebase.auth === 'function') {
      firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://' + firebaseEmulators.auth.host + ':' + firebaseEmulators.auth.port);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("To automatically connect the Firebase SDKs to running emulators, replace '/__/firebase/init.js' with '/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true' in your index.html");
  }
}
```

I have the following in my index.html file:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.24.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>
```

And this in the associated index.js file:

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

It works fine on the server in non-emulation (without the ?useEmulator=true).

I'm using the latest firebase cli 9.1.0

I've searched on here and google but can't seem to find an answer to this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure

Comment: Hi thanks, I have read that a number of times and seem to have all the relevant information in my firebase.json file:
```
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong version of Firebase 7.24.0 as opposed to over 8.  Just in case anyone else runs into this issue.